# Base class c# and Java different behaviour

Tags: java, c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class Based
{
   public string fun()
    {
        return " I am based";
    }
}

public class Derived :Based
{
    public string fun()
    {
        return " I am derived";
    }

}

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Based br = new Derived();;

            Console.Write(br.fun());
        }


    }
}
```

Hi All , I have written small piece of code in Java and as well as in c# also.

But I am getting different outputs. Could you please explain.

In java I am getting " I am derived" , while in c#  am getting " I am based" . Could  you please explain to me why? and also when do we use following syntax

```
Baseclass obj = new Derivedclass().
```

Comment: You should be getting a compilation warning in C# that is tell you that the derived method hides the base method and that you should use the `new` keyword if that was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). Java and C# has different default settings about it.

Java's `Derived class` always override its parent's method, however in C# we can define whether the child object created from parent class override its parent's method or not.

Here's how in C#:

**To Override**

1. Add `virtual` classification to the parent's method.
2. Add `override` classification to the child's method.

**Not to Override**

1. Add `virtual` classification to the parent's method.
2. Add `new` classification to the child's method.

Answer (score 12):

In Java all methods are `virtual` by default, but in C# they are not.
Therefore in C# you have to mark virtual methods manually.

Modify your code:

```
public class Based
{
    public virtual string fun()
    {
        return "I am base";
    }
}

public class Derived : Based
{
    public override string fun()
    {
        return "I am derived";
    }
}
```